# Is it possible to set Windows 7 to download updates now, but install them on the next shutdown?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, reboot, popups

Since I really don't like being reminded of an update that requires a reboot<sup>1</sup>, is it possible to have *manual* updates install when shutting down the next time? Automatic updating does this, but it's really annoying having to wait for quite some updates when I just wanted to shut down my PC<sub>(and pull the plug, that's why I don't simply let it shutdown on its own)</sub>. So

> Can the Windows 7 update be set to install updates on shutdown (like automatic updating does) but let me manually determine at *which* shutdown it shall do so?

Alternatively, changing the auto-update such that a don't-install-updates-now shutdown is possible would also be a solution.

<sup>1</sup><sub>especially while watching movies, and *yes*, I know I can set the reminder to four hours, but where's the option "don't remind me, I know that a computer can be restarted"?</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the closest to a solution, making the "Install updates and Shut Down" a non-default option in the shutdown menu.

> Add a 32-bit DWORD value called `NoAUAsDefaultShutdownOption` to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU` with a value of 1. No reboot should be necessary.

source: [howtogeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/stop-windows-update-from-hijacking-the-sleep-button/), found via [this SU answer](https://superuser.com/questions/104771/how-to-shut-down-the-computer-without-the-update-on-windows-7/117483#117483)