# Windows 10 - Controlling Automatic Update

Tags: windows-10, updates

I'm currently running Windows 7 but I'll probably get a new PC with Windows 10 Pro this year.   I've heard horror stories about automatic updates with Windows 10 happening at unpredictible times and causing big problems so I'm trying to understand them.   [**This question**](https://superuser.com/questions/946957/stopping-all-automatic-updates-windows-10) implies you can "**defer**" them but was a little unclear about defer them to exactly when, or how long?   Likewise the suggestion about Active Hours was a little unclear about how rigorously Microsoft follows it, i.e., if I say my "active" hours are 8AM to 6AM, does that guarantee that updates will only happen between 6-8AM?

I do professional video production so I'm often in the middle of big projects with tight schedules, and my PC is often running long multi-hour exports or conversions.   Overnight I'm often running batch-jobs, complete backups, malware scans or de-frags.  So an unscheduled reboot or interruption could be disastrous.

How do I exercise precise control over this risk?   I'd be perfectly happy to run an Update every single day as long as I could start it manually to make sure that no backups, exports, de-frags are running at the time.

Comment: Check this thread: http://superuser.com/questions/946957/stopping-all-automatic-updates-windows-10?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: If you had actually read my question you would have noticed that that was the thread I referenced in it.

Comment: You might check this if this gives you a [potential workaround](http://superuser.com/questions/1030085/with-windows-10-how-can-i-shut-down-without-installing-updates/1130295#1130295) way to potentially control when the updates are applied. Otherwise, following best practices for data backups and fast OS restore, recovery, imaging, etc. should be followed as with any critical data and system operations.

Comment: "_following best practices for data backups and fast OS restore, recovery, imaging, etc. should be followed as with any critical data and system operations_ "  If course best practice should be followed, but how does that address or control Windows 10 interruptions from updates?

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer:**

> Get Windows 10 Pro or better

With the aforementioned versions of Windows 10, you can get better control over auto-updates, although if you ignore too long, it will get less willing to wait.

**Less Desirable Answer:**

Even with Windows 10 Home you can get control over the auto-updates, by marking your internet connection as `Metered`.  In this case Windows will not auto download the updates, and thus cannot autoupdate.

([Source](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-win_upgrade/windows-10-automatic-updates/44b16bb2-9773-42a4-a25c-59f187f0f5f9))

Comment: "_With the aforementioned versions of Windows 10, you can get better control over auto-updates, although if you ignore too long, it will get less willing to wait._"  Better than the Home version, sure, but as I said in my OP I'll be getting the Pro version anyway.   So my questions apply to the Pro version.   How do heavy, professional users of Windows 10 Pro deal with these issues?

Comment: On Windows 10 Pro and Enterprise you can schedule them is a very similar manner to Windows 7.

Comment: I know there are scheduling options for Enterprise, but I'm unaware of scheduling options for Pro -  could you elaborate or provide a link?

Comment: There is Source link in the post.

Answer (score 0):

**Windows 10 implements mandatory updates for *consumer* products.**

Business/Enterprise users may delay updates up to 8 months, unless they are on a "Long Term Servicing Branch", where feature updates may be delayed from implementation indefinitely.

The scheduling system has resulted in consumer complaints, so it's best to check inside Windows 10 when updates are scheduled to be installed. This tends to be when you use your computer the least (over night).

**EDIT:** Instructions on how to "join" the CBB, or current branch for business is provided in the last link, but here's the general idea in a single image.

[image: How to get CBB in Windows 10 as of Jan 2017.]

URL Links:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10#Feature_updates

http://www.urtech.ca/2015/12/sovled-how-to-get-windows-current-branch-for-business/

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by  a "business or enterprise" user?   I am a business.   But I don't see a "business" version of Windows 10, just a Pro version.   My understanding of the "Enterprise" version is that it's not for sale, only "rent" as a subscription.    Also what **exactly** does "delay" mean?    Delay to a **specific** time?   Do I get to pick when it runs, or does the update only run at some random time of Microsoft's choosing?

Comment: @user316117 Microsoft has significantly shifted Windows to SaaS, or "Software as a Service". This means that there are significantly more updates, and in a shorter span of time. Editions don't really exist as they used to. Delay means that you can ignore the update, and do not have to apply it until that "period" is up. How fine the "period" is, it's not clear from any source. You can see the edit in my answer for a clarification on how to join the "CBB" or current business branch.

Comment: Thanks but I still can't tell from this information, or ( https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows/manage/waas-manage-updates-wufb) what **exactly** "defer" means and whether it means I can schedule updates.     I can't **possibly** be the only person here who uses Windows for intensive production work and runs his PC's overnight.   (the name of this StackExchange site is "SuperUser" so I assume people here are not casual home users)   What do other intensive users do in practice to avoid update problems with Windows 10?