# How can I prevent Windows from applying updates when shutting down when low UPS charge is left?

Tags: shutdown, ups

My PC is connected to power supply via UPS. It can provide emergency supply for about 5 minutes. This could be not enough to install updates when I push 'Power' button on my PC.
So, my question is: is there any function in Windows to do emergency shutdown without installing updates?

My question is related to Windows 2012 R2, Windows 2016 and Windows 10.

Comment: This has been asked and answered here: https://serverfault.com/questions/107010/restart-a-ms-server-2008-without-it-installing-updates See if that works for you.

Comment: Windows 10 is very forceful and I’m not sure if there is a safe way to do this. AFAIK, the `shutdown /r /t 0` trick does not work on Win 10. I’ve decided to live with it.

Comment: Are you looking for a manual solution, script, or something else?

Comment: In Win 7 "Restart" (in the Start menu) skips updates, "Shutdown" installs the updates.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/104771/how-to-shut-down-the-computer-without-the-update-on-windows-7?rq=1

Comment: I'm looking for official solution. What Microsoft thinks about that? Do they care about the scenario I described?

Answer (score -1):

I've used <kbd>Alt-F4</kbd> to shut down not only apps, but Win7.  Doing this on Win10 brings up the same dialog as Win7, which always offered the option of just "Shut Down" with another option having the "Install Windows Updates" ability.

My computer doesn't have Updates to do ATM, so I can't confirm if it still has the "Shut Down" option separately.

Edit:

> [With Windows 10 how can I shut down without installing updates?](https://superuser.com/questions/1030085/with-windows-10-how-can-i-shut-down-without-installing-updates)

That thread has some options, although they don't include an official MS solution.  I can't find anything, in my short search, that says Microsoft has an official solution for this situation.  It mes me think they either haven't considered this situation, considered it too low a probability event to bother with, or they just don't care.

Comment: The question is essentially about scripting the process for automated function on the battery. Manual operations are not applicable responses.

Comment: Where is the "scripting the process" mentioned, or even implied?  OP says PC, not server.  OP also says "when I push 'Power' button", more than implying that manual processes are acceptable.

Comment: Question is about computers connected to a UPS, the correct assumption then is that he is looking for a method that can be triggered by the UPS, a script. The mention of a power button within this context is more likely to mean that even when OP presses the power button it still goes through installing updates.

Comment: I've personally used UPSs on desktops without any expectation of a shutdown script.  I've also set up many desktops for companies desktops without shutdown scripts.  Simply saying "UPS" doesn't imply anything about scripting to me, so that's not a "correct assumption" if you're going to assume an assumption..

Comment: Actually I wasn't asking about scripting. I was asking about a solution when my battery (UPS or laptop, whatever) is running out, and I'm sure the Update will be interrupted in the middle of process. And I need some official answer. What Microsoft thinks about such scenarios?