# How to disable "Update and shutdown" and restore plain "Shutdown"

Tags: boot, windows-8.1, shutdown

My Windows 8.1 - Basic Edition PC forces me to update when I try to shut it down every day and I go along with it. When turning it back on, It'll update for like 5 minutes and then say something like, "We Couldn't Complete the Updates Undoing Changes" and then it restarts. Why let it update when it is going to do that same process **EVERY SINGLE TIME**. This makes my PC take about 30 minutes just to start up. I was wondering if there was a way to disable forced updates, so I can just shut down my PC normally.

Here is one of the update's info that failed:

[image: failed update pic]

Comment: You should determine the reason updates are failing to install.  If you are able to disable Windows Update entirely depends on the edition of Windows you are running.

Comment: Similar question>>>>>>https://superuser.com/questions/104771/how-to-shut-down-the-computer-without-the-update-on-windows-7?rq=1

Comment: @Adam5 - Instead of submitting a temporary comment you should edit your question.  Only improving and providing the required information to help you might result in your question being reopened.  Please do not respond to this comment with another comment.  You have not indicated if you are using Windows 8.1 or Windows 8.1 Professional, it makes a difference, if you are able to easily disable Windows Updates or not